# What does this default RSpec statement mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

```
User.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
```

What does that statement mean? `these` isn't instantiated anywhere as meaning anything.

The whole statement is this :

```
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "updates the requested user" do
      User.should_receive(:find).with("37") { mock_user }
      User.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
      put :update, :id => "37", :user => {'these' => 'params'}
    end
```

I say this because I'm getting an error :

```
unknown attribute: these
```

Which is coming from aforementioned scenario..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is saying that the method `update_attributes` should be invoked on the `User` model with an argument of `{'these' => 'params'}` during whatever test is being run.

Basically the following is expected to happen during the execution:

```
User.update_attributes({'these' => 'params'})
```

More here: http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/message_expectations.html

Comment: Right, but what is `these` and what is `params`?

Comment: That's just an example hash. You would replace it with whatever your controller is expecting. For example, you might be updating the user's name, so it would be `with({:first_name => "something", :last_name => "else"})`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to replace the hash ({'these' => 'params'}). Think of it as a contract. I have said that when I PUT, the following hash should be received by my objects update_attributes model. In the next line, you call the update method and the contract is checked.